# Batman Begins credit scene

Tags: credits, batman-begins

I was rewatching Batman begins and watched it until the credits roll. I noticed that **Liam Neeson** was listed as **Ducard**, **Ken Watanabe** was listed as **Ra's Al ghul**. It made me ponder over the entire movie as to whether Liam Neeson's character was really Ra's Al Ghul or did he take over the league after the death of Ken Watanabe because I remember towards the end, Bruce Wayne's character complimenting on Ra's deception tricks when they meet at Wayne Manor again. Is that a minor glitch or intended to be food for thought?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think Neeson was indeed Ra's Al Ghul, and that the credits were only that way because that was how they would be listed on IMDb - if their true roles had been listed then the big surprise would be revealed before the film opened. This is similar to Marion Cotillard's character being listed on IMDb as Talia Al Ghul a year before TDKR opened (the listing was changed recently) thus ruining *that* big twist.